# Passing arguments to docker compose file when using it for swarm

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have a docker swarm and I deploy my service stack using

"docker stack deploy --compose-file mycompose.yaml myservice".

I want to pass some values that will be using in this yaml file. Can I pass it from command line or through some other way?

Answer (score 1):

With the old docker-compose you could create an .env file and expose environmental variables to the containers that way.  Referencing ${env} in the .yml file.  It seems swarm does something similar, not sure about the .env file tho.  I'm still working on getting a swarm setup so I'm stuck on compose for now.  I found these but haven't tried it myself yet, good luck.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

And this too!
https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/